# Odd behavior - C Priority Queue with strings

Tags: c, string, file-io, strtok

I'm working on a priority queue for an algorithms class homework, using C. The priority queue is working and not a problem. However, we have to read lines from a file containing a string/char array, and a number for the priority. Here is my `main` function that does all of that:

```
int main() {
  p_queue *q = make_queue(2); 
  FILE *of = fopen("sportsball2.txt", "r"); 
  char buffer[128]; //no name is longer than this
  char *part, *assign; 
  int x; 

  while(!feof(of)) {
    fscanf(of, "%s\n", buffer); 

    if(strcmp("GO!", buffer) != 0) {
      part = strtok(buffer, "/");
      assign = part; 

      part = strtok(NULL, "/");
      x = atoi(part); 

      insert(q, assign, x); 
    } else { 
       entr_struct *t = pop(q);
       if(!t) {
         printf("No players waiting to enter!"); 
       } else {
         printf("%s%s\n", t->entry, " enters the game!"); 
       }
    }
  }

  destroy_queue(q); //calls a custom memory free function 

  return EXIT_SUCCESS; 
}
```

It all works as expected *unless* the `else` triggers, in which case the `pop` returns that the entry at the top of the queue had the string "GO!" (the contents of `buffer` if the `else` branch is taken). I have specifically checked and made sure that the correct values *are* making their way into the `assign` and `x` variables, so I have no idea what is happening here. I am relatively new to C, so it's entirely possible that I'm missing something well-known and obvious.

Comment: Where is new memory for the strings allocated?

Comment: Start by [fixing this: `while(!feof(of))`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong/5432517#5432517)

Comment: does pop return a pointer or a 'entr_struct' ?

Comment: @dataNinja124, a pointer to an `entr_struct`. The priority queue itself is declared as `entr_struct **queue`.

Comment: Change `while(!feof(of)) { fscanf(of, "%s\n", buffer);` to `while(fscanf(of, "%s", buffer) == 1);`  (while condition and no \n)

Comment: I'm thinking one of your issues is that you never allocate (using malloc()) any memory to hold the structure (you just create pointers) unless that is in a part of the code you are not showing.

Comment: No, there are allocation functions for both the entries and the master priority queue higher up in the code.